# Real time switching for playing audio as microphone input for online speaking in external app

Tags: audio, microphone

I like to play my podcast played from some other apps like Telegram or Castbox into my realtime mic which is played in another app like Hangouts or WhatsApp conference, two-person calls, or for streaming a live podcast.

I found some apps like [Lesser AudioSwitch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nordskog.LesserAudioSwitch) or [Microphone Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=multimediasol.app.microphoneall) which don't work for this purpose.

There are apps like [VB-CABLE Virtual Audio Device](https://www.vb-audio.com/Cable/index.htm) as per [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20646319), but it is for Windows, not for Android.

There are [some apps](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/call-voicechanging-android-app-29358.html) which [convert audio call in realtime](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-good-real-time-voice-changer-app-for-Android), but is there any way to combine played audio with the phone mic into some other apps like Phone or Hangouts?